Can't run the node after updating to polkadot-v1.8.0
My node cannot create genesis configuration after updating to polkadot-v1.8.0. There is some sort of allocation error, but I am not sure where it is coming from.
❯ ./target/release/vtb-node build-spec --dev --raw
2024-09-18 01:03:18 Building chain spec    
Error: Service(
  Other(
    "wasm call error Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed\n
     WASM backtrace:\nerror while executing at wasm backtrace:\n
     0: 0x76e8c - vtb_node_runtime.wasm!__rg_oom\n
     1: 0x3557 - vtb_node_runtime.wasm!__rust_alloc_error_handler\n
     2: 0x38a3 - vtb_node_runtime.wasm!alloc::alloc::handle_alloc_error::h19e50b8409556383\n
     3: 0x371d - vtb_node_runtime.wasm!alloc::raw_vec::handle_error::hf690fbb5ea5797f9\n
     4: 0x259401 - vtb_node_runtime.wasm!frame_support::genesis_builder_helper::create_default_config::h33cbb18701376c12\n
     5: 0x3ebe88 - vtb_node_runtime.wasm!GenesisBuilder_create_default_config"
  )
)

I would appreciate any insight about why this could be happening.
